# Javascript multiple fields validating

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation

First, I have to validate that id and password textboxes are not empty(That one's working). Then I have to validate on the same form that id on textbox needs to be a number and also a number between 3000 and 3999 (That one doesn't work). Any ideas on what's wrong with my code?

```
function validatefunctions() {
  if (document.getElementById('idtb').value === '') {
    alert('You need to enter a Customer ID');
    return false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('pwtb').value === '') {
    alert('Please enter your password');
    return false;
  }
  var custID;
  custID = document.getElementsByName("idtb").valueOf();

  if (custID !== isNan) {
    alert("Customer ID needs to be numeric");
    return false;
  }
  if (custID < 3000) {
    alert("ID must be above 3000");
    return false;
  }
  if (custID > 3999) {
    alert("ID must be below 3999");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `.valueOf();` is incorrect. You can use `.value` instead to get the value (like you've done in yoru `if` statements). To check if a string is _not_ a number you can use `isNaN(custID)`, which will give true when the `custID` is not a number, and `false` when it is a number

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***textbox needs to be a number and also a number between 3000 and 3999 (That one doesn't work)***

Why don't use input type *number* specifying the *min* and *max* attribute:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="3000" max="3999" value="3000">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
function validatefunctions() {
  if (document.getElementById('idtb').value === '') {
    alert('You need to enter a Customer ID');
    return false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('pwtb').value === '') {
    alert('Please enter your password');
    return false;
  }

  var custID = document.getElementById('idtb').value;
  if (Number.isNaN(parseInt(custID))) {
    alert("Customer ID needs to be numeric");
    return false;
  }
  
  if (parseInt(custID) < 3000) {
    alert("ID must be above 3000");
    return false;
  }
  
  if (parseInt(custID) > 3999) {
    alert("ID must be below 3999");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form  action="#" onsubmit="return validatefunctions()" method="post">

  Customer ID: <input type="text" name="idtb" id="idtb"><br /><br />

  Password: <input type="text" name="pwtb" id="pwtb"><br /><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're code is near to correct but you should use Number function of inbuilt javascript function which will return the data-type of value.

so you just need to use Number.isNaN function rather than document.getElementsByName("idtb").valueOf() in your code./